# hcitool cc and hcitool auth returns Input/output error

Tags: bluetooth, hci

I have successfully set up and enabled Bluetooth on my server running Debian Buster. That in itself is quite an achievement. Anyhow, I am trying to use a Node package called `node-bluetooth-serial-port` to connect to a tiny Bluetooth speaker with a display. I manage to list/scan devices, but it cannot send anything to the device. I'm thinking this is because my server hasn't been paired with the device yet.

```
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
        11:22:33:44:55:66       TimeBox-mini-audio

$ sudo hcitool cc 11:22:33:44:55:66; sudo hcitool auth 11:22:33:44:55:66
HCI authentication request failed: Input/output error
```

So hcitool can find the device, but it cannot connect to it, for some reason. `dmesg` doesn't show me any errors what so ever.

I have tried to pair with other devices (like my phone), but that doesn't work either.

The device does not require a 4-digit pin to auth.

What can I do here?